# Cannot read property 'push' of undefined in controller and their service

Tags: angularjs, mean

this is my controller of story file

```
 angular.module('storyCtrl', ['storyService'])
   .controller('StoryController', function(Story, socketio) {
    var vm = this;
    Story.all()
        .then(function(response) {
        //.success(function(data) {
            //console.log(data);

            vm.stories = response;
        });
    vm.createStory = function() {
        vm.processing = true;
        vm.message = '';
        Story.create(vm.storyData)
            .then(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            //.success(function(data) {
                vm.processing = false;
                vm.storyData = {};
                vm.message = data.message;
            });

    };

    socketio.on('story', function(response) {
        vm.stories.push(response);
    })

    })

.controller('AllStoriesController', function(stories, socketio) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.stories = stories.data;
    socketio.on('story', function(data) {
        vm.stories.push(data);
    });
  });
```

and this is my story service file

```
angular.module('storyService', [])

.factory('Story', function($http) {


var storyFactory = {};

storyFactory.allStories = function() {
    return $http.get('/api/all_stories');
}

storyFactory.all = function() {
    return $http.get('/api/');
}

storyFactory.create = function(storyData) {
    return $http.post('/api/', storyData);
  }

    return storyFactory;


   })

   .factory('socketio', function($rootScope) {

    var socket = io.connect();
    return {

    on: function(eventName, callback) {
        socket.on(eventName, function() {
            var args = arguments;
            $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                callback.apply(socket, args);
            });
        });
    },

    emit: function(eventName, data, callback) {
        socket.emit(eventName, data, function() {
            var args = arguments;
            $rootScope.apply(function() {
                if(callback) {
                    callback.apply(socket, args);
                }
            });
        });
    }

   };

 });
```

i have get an error becouse i update angular 1.3 to 1.6 this is working fine in 1.3 but it is not working in Angular 1.6 is there any issue upgrading for angular version

i have got an error for above controller line  "vm.stories.push(response);"

```
     TypeError: vm.stories.push is not a function
     at n.<anonymous> (storyCtrl.js:36)
     at storyService.js:38
     at Scope.$eval (angular.js:17972)
     at Scope.$apply (angular.js:18072)
     at n.<anonymous> (storyService.js:37)
     at n.emit (universalModuleDefinition:2)
     at n.onevent (universalModuleDefinition:3)
     at n.onpacket (universalModuleDefinition:3)
     at n.<anonymous> (universalModuleDefinition:3)
     at n.emit (universalModuleDefinition:2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `vm.stories` is `undefined`. Why? - `$http.get('/api/');` returns no data.

However, you can fix it by replacing `vm.stories = response` inside `Story.all()` resolve callback with:

```
vm.stories = response || [];
```

It will guard you from exceptions (similar to yours)

**EDIT**

also initiate `stories` (in controller) at the beginning as:

```
var vm = this;
vm.stories = [];
```

Comment: i had changed the code according to you but this is display same error

Comment: Story.all()
   .then(function(response) {
   
    vm.stories = response || [];

   });

Comment: @MuneshKumar that means you call `push` before you initialize `stories`